# Configuring LAMP to Send Mails

Tags: php, apache, sendmail, vps

I have LAMP stack installed on VPS. Would like to send mails using PHP's internal mail() function.

I have an account with Fastmail, and have credentials for their SMTP Server. So would like to use that for mailing purposes instead of setting one of my own. Additionally, there should be a way to throttle/queue the mails.

Can someone guide me to the direction to where should I start?

**EDIT:** I am on Ubuntu on Linode.

**NOTE:** This is not for spamming. Its meant for my side project.

Comment: assure us that you won't be spamming, OK?

Comment: voting to close, assuming intent to spam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Php mailer class [ http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/ ] and just write simple wrapper for queing tasks,setting up email credentials for sending emails .

Answer (score 0):

depending upon your os `Windows` or `*nix`

configure your smtp service accordingly

[This will help u](http://www.sitepoint.com/advanced-email-php/)