# Cannot get email script working

Tags: php, email

Here is the code I have in contact.php:

```
<?php
    mail('philovesdogs@gmail.com','sdf','sadfsad');
    echo 'Ok';
?>
```

I put the echo in just to make sure that PHP was working on the page. I uploaded the page to my LAMP server and opened the page. I saw ok. I checked my email however (and my Spam folder) and no email was sent.

Comment: can you check your logs on your server?

Comment: Enable error reporting, check whether there is an SMTP server running and you have configured it in your php.ini.

Comment: You can also look at PHPMailer (http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to configure and keep running SMTP server. Review questions like this: [Configuring LAMP to Send Mails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722941/configuring-lamp-to-send-mails)